# getting the contents of each entry in a loop

Tags: python, tkinter, printing, tkinter-entry

I'm using tkinter with Python to get a query from the user and print the contents of each entry in a loop. However, only the text of the the last entry gets printed. What should I do to fix the problem?

```
for i in range(len(labels)):
    label=Label(V,text=i, relief=RIDGE,width=8)
    label.pack()
    label.grid(row=counter,column=1,padx=5,pady=5)
    entry = Entry(V, relief=SUNKEN,width=30,justify=RIGHT)
    entry.pack()
    entry.grid(row=counter,column=0,padx=10,pady=5)
    def showevent (event):
        print entry.get()

    entry.bind("<Return>", showevent)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a common misconception with closures.  Basically, `entry` is looked up when the function is *run*, not defined.  The simple fix is to make it a default argument:

```
def showevent(event,entry=entry):
    print entry.get()
```

This works because default arguments are evaluated at the time the function is created, not when it is called so you always get the entry that you want.